# disabling row reorder in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am using DataTables Row Reordering Add-on (http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html ) and I want to be able to disable the reordeing in JS. I used code similar to the following code:

```
if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
  $("#" + parameters.TableId).dataTable(
                {
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bSort": true,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bAutoWidth": true
                }).rowReordering({ sURL: parameters.sURL, iIndexColumn: parameters.iIndexColumn });
} else {
            $("#" + parameters.TableId).dataTable(
                {
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bSort": false,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bAutoWidth": true
                });//.rowReordering({ sURL: parameters.sURL, iIndexColumn: parameters.iIndexColumn });
```

but it doesn't work (I am still able to drag and drop rows, but since I made the bSort to false, it doesn't save the sort order. I want to disable the drag and drop). What can I do?

Comment: If you are still able to drag and drop rows (a feature only available with`.rowReordering()` , that would suggest that your logic in the if statement is wrong, because it never enters the else section.

Comment: Wait a minute, can you post the start of that `if() {} else {}` statement?

Comment: Code updated. Also I checked and the elese is called, but doesn't remove the draganddrop (I cansee the ffect as when else is called, then no sort took place, but drag and drop happens.

Comment: Is the check-box defaulted to checked when the page loads?

Comment: Yes, But I can change it to not checked if that helps !

Comment: Try it, the first datatable could be getting cached. If so, the behavior should switch (unable to drag items when checkbox is checked after page load).

Comment: The reason that I am doing this in JS is to not to do a post back.

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little i found that sortable is used but disabling is slightly different then enabling it.

```
$("tbody", oTable).sortable({"disabled" : true});

$("tbody", oTable).sortable( "enable" );
```

Answer (score -1):

use:

`$("#your_table_id .ui-sortable" ).sortable("disable");` - to disable

`$("#your_table_id .ui-sortable" ).sortable("enable");` - to enable